# Update multiple records and insert into another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert

How do you update several rows and for each one that was updated, insert a row in another table.

Pseudo example:

```
 update Table1 
 set CustQty = 20, set @UpdatedPk = PkRow 
 where Table1.customer_id = "A1233" 
   and Table1.CustQty  < 20 
 insert into Table2 (Table1Pk) values (@UpdatedPk)
```

Comment: Don't repeat the `SET` keyword for setting multiple columns to new values - just use `SET CustQty= 20, @UpdatedPk = PkRow .....`

Answer (score 2):

Use `OUTPUT` clause:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET CustQty = 20
OUTPUT INSERTED.PKRow INTO Table1PK
WHERE Table1.customer_id = "A1233" AND Table1.CustQty  < 20
```

Comment: Giorgi, I like this approach.  Thank you.